# Is the answer of $\ \ 2415^n \ mod \ \ 2556 \ \ $ is only $711$ and $1989$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+} >1 \ \ ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

Is the answer of  $\ \  2415^n \ mod \ \ 2556 \ \  $ is only  $711$ and $1989$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}  >1 \ \ ?$

If it's true, how to prove that ?

I try to  expand  $(2556 - 141)^n $ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}  >1$ , but it doesn't make sense.

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2415%5En%20%20mod%202556),

It seems like  remainder is $711$ for $n=3,5,7,9,11,13,15,...$

and remainder is $1989$ for $n=2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,...$

But I don't know how to prove that , or maybe the answer of  $\ \  2415^n \ mod \ \ 2556 \ \  $ is not  only  $711$ and $1989$ $?$

Thank you so much for every comments .

Answer (score 1):

We have $$1989^2\equiv 1989\ (\ mod\ 2556\ )$$ and therefore $$1989^n\equiv 1989 \ (\ mod\ 2556\ )$$ for all $n\ge 1$

That means $$2415^{2n}\equiv \ 1989\ (\ mod\ 2556\ )$$ for all $n\ge 1$

Additionally, we have $$2415\times 1989\equiv\ 711\ (\ mod\ 2556\ )$$ showing $$2415^{2n+1}\equiv 711\ (\ mod\ 2556\ )$$ for all $n\ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

Peter has answered the question, but here is a little more to the story:

$2556$ is $4\times 639 = 2^2 \times 9\times 71 = 2^2\times 3^2 \times 71$. Therefore, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can tell the behavior of powers of a number mod $2556$ by considering it mod $2^2 = 4$, mod $3^2=9$, and mod $71$.

Now $2415$ is $3=-1$ mod $4$, $3$ mod $9$, and $1$ mod $71$.

Because it is $-1$ mod $4$, its powers alternate between $-1$ and $+1$ mod $4$.

Because it is $3$ mod $9$, all its powers after the first power are $0$ mod $9$.

Because it is $1$ mod $71$, all its powers are $1$ mod $71$.

This explains the situation. The even powers are all $+1$ mod $4$, $0$ mod $9$, and $1$ mod $71$. Mod $2556$, this forces them all to be $1989$. The odd powers *beyond the first* are $-1$ mod $4$, $0$ mod $9$, and $1$ mod $71$. This forces them to be $711$ mod $2556$.